# Strange behaviour when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php

I am testing a code sample that pass a value from php to JavaScript in order to test the form value.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Page 1</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <form method="post" action="essai.php">
    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="mail"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
 </form>

     <?php
        if (isset($_POST['mail'])){
            $data=789;
        }
    ?>    


  <script>


    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

    $(function(){

      $("form").on("submit", function() {
      if($("#mail").val().length < 4) {
          alert(data);
          return false;
      }

    });
  });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So it suppose to pop up a message (789) when the input is less than 4 caracters.

When I enter one letter in the form, then **directly** press enter the pop up appears.
**But**, when I fill the form (still with one letter), click somewhere else on the page, **and then** click validate, the pop up does not appears.

I can't see why there is this behaviour, maybe the fact that I click somewhere else on the page, undo the JavaScript action, but why ?

Someone has an explanation ?

Thank you

Comment: @LucaJung Same problem when I move php code out from the script tags, I will edit my post

Comment: you're using jquery outside a document.ready()..wrap it in and see if it works

Comment: @BernardParah - There's already a document ready handler, though in any case the JS is after the element it binds the event handler to so it doesn't need a document ready handler.

Comment: @BernardParah I just tried ($( document ).ready(function() { MY Javascript });) But still the same problem...

Comment: Your JS works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/mun1d6p0/ - but, what value does `$data` have the first time the page loads, if it is being set in your PHP from a POST parameter?

Comment: @nnnnnn  If I set the value of $data to 1 before the condition (if(isset)..) the pop up appears in any case (if I click elsewhere or not) but has always the value of 1... which means it does not go in the if statement

Comment: My point is that when your page *first* loads, presumably it was not the result of a previous post, so `if (isset($_POST['mail']))` will be false and `$data` will not get set. What would you expect your alert to show if `$data` wasn't set?

Comment: no man, the problem is that the var instanciated with the `$_POST['mail']` data does not goes into the on submit function the 1st time I submit the form, but it does the times after..

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to this

```
 <form method="post" action="essai.php">
    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="mail"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Validate" />
 </form>
```

And PHP to this

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $data=789;
        }
    ?>
```

JS

```
  <script>


    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

    $(function(){

      $("form").on("submit", function() {
      if($("#mail").val().length < 4) {
          alert(data);
          return false;
      }
      else { $(this.form).submit(); }

    });
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: See, first he's done this `isset($_POST['mail'])` in the code but trying to submit the form with `Validate` button. Let him try and check whether he needs it.

Comment: There is an input element with `name="mail"`, but in any case the behaviour the OP asked about is within the JS event handler *before* submission, not with the PHP.